# Shouldn't `softtabstop` be set, when using option 2 in `:h tabstop` to configure Vim to use spaces for `<Tab>`s?

Tags: insert-mode, tab-characters

I want to configure Vim to use spaces for `<Tab>`s everywhere. Therefore, I've had a look at `:h tabstop` to figure out how to perform the configuration.

Looking at the help text, option 2. seems appropriate for my use case. However, it doesn't mention `softtabstop`, why not? Without setting `softtabstop`, every `<Tab>` I insert result in the default number of spaces for the `filetype` (4 for Python), and not the value configured for `tabstop`?

Shouldn't `softtabstop` be set when using option 2? If not, then indentation and `<Tab>`s inserted in Insert mode results in different number of spaces, which is awkward.

Bonus: What is the standard way of handling `<Tab>s` in Vim that most users opt for?

Bonus: what is meant by *"Then Vim
will use a mix of tabs and spaces, but typing `<Tab>` and `<BS>` will
behave like a tab appears every 4 (or 3) characters."* in option 1?

`:h tabstop`:

```
Number of spaces that a <Tab> in the file counts for.  Also see
|:retab| command, and 'softtabstop' option.

Note: Setting 'tabstop' to any other value than 8 can make your file
appear wrong in many places (e.g., when printing it).

There are four main ways to use tabs in Vim:
1. Always keep 'tabstop' at 8, set 'softtabstop' and 'shiftwidth' to 4
   (or 3 or whatever you prefer) and use 'noexpandtab'.  Then Vim
   will use a mix of tabs and spaces, but typing <Tab> and <BS> will
   behave like a tab appears every 4 (or 3) characters.
2. Set 'tabstop' and 'shiftwidth' to whatever you prefer and use
   'expandtab'.  This way you will always insert spaces.  The
   formatting will never be messed up when 'tabstop' is changed.
3. Set 'tabstop' and 'shiftwidth' to whatever you prefer and use a
   |modeline| to set these values when editing the file again.  Only
   works when using Vim to edit the file.
4. Always set 'tabstop' and 'shiftwidth' to the same value, and
   'noexpandtab'.  This should then work (for initial indents only)
   for any tabstop setting that people use.  It might be nice to have
   tabs after the first non-blank inserted as spaces if you do this
   though.  Otherwise aligned comments will be wrong when 'tabstop' is
   changed.
```

Comment: Anedocte: That is the correct way to do. But the best way is to simply blindly set values and stick to the permutation that happens to work out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, it doesn't mention softtabstop, why not?

I suppose it's because `softtabstop` can be set up independently.

> Without setting softtabstop, every Tab I insert result in the default number of spaces for the filetype (4 for Python), and not the value configured for tabstop?

Actually it's vice versa. If you miss it, maybe it's because of Python's ftplugin who had already `set softtabstop=4` for you.

> If not, then indentation and Tabs inserted in Insert mode results in a different number of spaces, which is awkward.

If one has `set smarttab` then tab is forced to shiftwidth at line beginning, so the argument does not apply. However, `smarttab` is neither set by default nor mentioned there. So maybe we should blame Bram (or whoever wrote this topic) on this point.

> what is meant by "Then Vim will use a mix of tabs and spaces, but typing and will behave like a tab appears every 4 (or 3) characters."

Obviously, if one has `set noexpandtab`, while `softtabstop` is less than `tabstop`, then hitting tab several times may result in a full `tabstop` (or more). At that point Vim will "optimize" whitespace by inserting hard tabs as expected.

> What is the standard way of handling Tabs in Vim that most users opt for?

I don't know anything about "standards". I can only speak for myself. So what I have is

```
set tabstop& expandtab smarttab softtabstop=-1 shiftround shiftwidth=4
```

In principle, setting both `softtabstop` and `smarttab` is redundant yet it doesn't do any harm.

Comment: What exactly is the difference between `tabstop` and `softtabsstop`? Does `tabstop` define how many spaces a TAB accounts for, while `softtabstop` define how many spaces a TAB accounts for while performing editing in Insert mode, so that if `softtabstop` is greater than `tabstop`, then `softtabstop / tabstop` TABs are inserted and spaces for the rest, if `noexpandtab`? Where as `softtabspaces` spaces are inserted, if `expandtab`?

Comment: @Shuzheng Roughly speaking, `tabstop` is "space"-equivalent of every byte(9) from buffer; while `softtabstop` is "space"-equivalent of "tab" key hit.

Comment: @Shuzheng Of course, also rounding needs to be applied, so exact value is calculated dynamically.

Comment: What does `set tabstop&` mean? I would normally use `&` for something like `:echo &shiftwidth`.

Comment: @Shuzheng This is to reset to default value. Please, read `:h :set` if you still miss some syntax bits.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to off an alternative perspective for forcing spaces everywhere: leave `tabstop` alone unless you're viewing files with tabs and you want them to be skinnier to save on screen real-estate. (So, leave it as default, 8.) This is more realistic, though in general one cannot control how tabs appear in foreign environments.

Set `expandtab`, of course (note that in some filetypes, it should not be set! `make`, for example. The default ftplugin does this already, so that works out.)

Then, set locally `shiftwidth` and `softtabstop` for filetypes you need to change the indent settings. A quick `git-grep` in my Dotfiles shows some examples:

```
links/vim/after/ftplugin/applescript.vim:5:10:setlocal shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=2
links/vim/after/ftplugin/css.vim:6:10:setlocal shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=2
links/vim/after/ftplugin/gitcommit.vim:6:10:setlocal shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=2
links/vim/after/ftplugin/gitconfig.vim:8:20:setlocal tabstop=8 shiftwidth=8 softtabstop=8
links/vim/after/ftplugin/go.vim:10:10:setlocal shiftwidth=0
links/vim/after/ftplugin/html.vim:6:10:setlocal shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=2
links/vim/after/ftplugin/java.vim:6:10:setlocal shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=2
links/vim/after/ftplugin/javascript.vim:5:10:setlocal shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=2
links/vim/after/ftplugin/make.vim:6:10:setlocal shiftwidth=8
links/vim/after/ftplugin/matlab.vim:8:10:setlocal shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4
links/vim/after/ftplugin/ruby.vim:13:10:setlocal shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=2
links/vim/after/ftplugin/scala.vim:5:10:setlocal shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=2
links/vim/after/ftplugin/scss.vim:5:10:setlocal shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=2
links/vim/after/ftplugin/sh.vim:8:10:setlocal shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=2
links/vim/after/ftplugin/sml.vim:8:10:setlocal shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=2
links/vim/after/ftplugin/typescript.vim:5:10:setlocal shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=2
links/vim/after/ftplugin/verilog.vim:6:10:setlocal shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4
links/vim/after/ftplugin/vim.vim:6:10:setlocal shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=2
links/vim/after/ftplugin/xml.vim:5:10:setlocal shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=2
links/vim/after/ftplugin/yaml.vim:6:10:setlocal shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=2
links/vim/after/ftplugin/zsh.vim:8:10:setlocal shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=2
```

Note that I had to set `shiftwidth` back to 8 in makefiles (the ftplugin also sets `sofftabstop` to 0) and both to 0 in go files.

I do set `shiftround` so that `>` and `<` behave like I want. `i_CTRL-T` and `i_CTRL-D` always round to a multiple of `shiftwidth`, so this unifies them.

---

> However, it doesn't mention softtabstop, why not?

Sure it does, just not directly next to option 2:

```
Also see |:retab| command, and 'softtabstop' option.
```

> Bonus: what is meant by *"Then Vim will use a mix of tabs and spaces, but typing and will behave like a tab appears every 4 (or 3) characters."* in option 1?

As Matt mentions, certain combinations of indents may not align directly with tab-boundaries. Vim will use tabs where it can and then fill in spaces so the visual indent matches what would be there. Personally I find this a bit terrible, since (as noted) you cannot control how wide tabs are outside of your own environment. This means that using tabs to align code is liable to break when other people are viewing it. Spaces don't suffer from that.

---

More information in an excellent screencast: [Vimcasts: tabs and spaces](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/tabs-and-spaces/)

Comment: Thank you, Ben. So, you opt partially for option 1, namely setting `shiftwidth` and `softtabstop`; however, you set `expandtab`, while option 1 opt for `noexpandtab`, why?

Comment: Can you confirm the following: `tabstop` is used to define the width of a TAB in spaces; `softtabstop` is used to define the width of TABs in Insert mode, in which case `softtabstop / tabstop` TABs are inserted and spaces for the rest, if `noexpandtab`, or `softtabstop` spaces are inserted, if `expandtab`?

Comment: If `expandtab`, then `tabstop` only really applies to viewing (external) files with TABs?

Comment: re `expandtab`, I want spaces. `tabstop` defines how wide a Tab character appears (in spaces). `softtabstop` is what is used when pressing `<tab>`, `<bs>`, etc. Yes, with `expandtab`, `tabstop` only matters when the files have tabs (e.g., go, make, other people's files). See `:help` for each of the options for a more detailed description of what they do

Comment: Thanks, `<bs>` is for back-space (delete)? Why is that related to `<tab>`?

Comment: @Shuzheng insert mode, hit tab then backspace. What is deleted depends on your settings